# Triggering Bamboo unit tests after a git push action

Tags: git, unit-testing, bamboo

I have a task where i want to ensure that bamboo unit tests are run after a push action or after clicking the 'merge' button on the pull request page.

Every bug fix is done as part of a child branch of master, say master_bug1. 
When i do a 'git push -u origin master_bug1', i want the bamboo unit tests to be run for this branch.
Alternatively, after a git push is done and a pull request created and approved, on clicking the "merge" button, it should trigger the unit tests for the child branch and complete the merge ONLY if the unit tests did not cause any failure.

Are there any stash/bamboo plugins that do this or is there any way i can configure it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve it.
1) First way would be--You can enable triggers in Bamboo. you can use Stash Repository triggered trigger. Every time, any push activity is performed in Stash for configured repository, build will start.

2) Alternatively, you can use Post commit Web hooks. 
You can use 'Http Request Post Receive Hook' https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.aeffle.stash.plugin.stash-http-get-post-receive-hook/server/overview.

I am using both approaches, let me know if you want to more details.